# Проблема с билдом

Tags: c#, unity3d, build

Удалил из Package Manager Xiaomi SDK, после этого выдает 100 ошибок во время билда, установил заново, но ошибки выдает те-же, кто может помочь? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А точно тег C# соответствует действительности? Просто в ошибках пестрят упоминания JAVA.

Comment: ну я с# коды писал, возможно плагины Java? но я только встроенные использую, плюс к тому же до удаления Xiaomi SDK, раз сто я билдил и все было без проблем